# Adding an optional dictionary parameter

Tags: c#

How to add an optional dictionary type parameter to any method.

I want to add a new optional parameter  Dictionary to an existing method. I want to know if we could do this and if we could how could i default it to an empty dictionary of that type or null

Comment: You cannot provide a non-constant default-param. Thus you have to check for `null` within your method and assign an empty dictionary in that case as @Rahul mentioned

Comment: Adding an overload would be an option too.

Answer (score 5):

You can try like this:

```
void myFun(Dictionary<string, string> param = null)
{
    if(param == null) 
    param = new Dictionary<string,string>();
}
```

Comment: In newer versions, if you use `<Nullable>enable</Nullable>` the optional parameter needs to be defined as nullable `Dictionary<string, string>? param = null`

Answer (score 1):

```
 void Foo(Dictionary<string, string> parameter){
        if(parameter == null) parameter = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    }
```

You could also make the parameter optional:

```
void Foo(Dictionary<string, string> parameter = null)
{
    if(parameter == null) parameter = new Dictionary<string,string>();
}
```